Connect main mixer to individual in ear monitor mixer
I play drums and sing in a band. We use a digital mixer, the Behringer X Air XR18 as our main stage mixer. I also use a wired in-ear monitor system, with my own mixer, a small Behringer Xenyx 802.
Our XR18 has 6 Aux Outputs (mono, balanced XLR).
I always connected that to my mixer using a simple male XLR to female XLR cable, into my Xenyx MIC input. That always worked fine, but I had a gig last week and we were playing in a big stage so we didn't have to bring our PA and mixer. When we were at soundcheck, the sound technician advised me to use a female XLR to 1/4" TRS Jack cable instead of the usual XLR to XLR that I always used. He said it would be better because I would plug it into the LINE IN of channel 1 of my Xenyx mixer, instead of the MIC, so the signal would not be so strong, and so it would be less likely to clip, even when the gain was all the way to the left.
That would allow me to turn my individual channels up (on the mixing app) without losing sound quality (for example the kick drum and snare).
What are your thoughts on this?
Is this right? Should I get a XLR to 1/4" TRS Jack cable and plug it in the LINE IN instead of using a XLR to my MIC input?
Thank you in advance.

Well, what happened when you did as he suggested?

He is correct.
On the Xenyx 802, the gain for the mic inputs is a range from +10 to +60 dB, i.e. the lowest gain you can select is +10 dB.
You are connecting to a line output. If the signal coming out of that gets loud, adding 10 dB of gain may lead to clipping.
The line inputs have a gain range from -10 dB to +40 dB, which is more suitable for the line output of a mixer.
For your own setup, you can avoid this problem: you can always reduce the signal coming out of the XR18 by pulling down the fader on your AUX output.
If you're playing gigs where the main mixer is controlled by someone else, it's one more thing to check when you're setting up. Using a line input avoids that.
